# How to find out number of elements in MongoDB array?

Tags: database, mongodb, mapreduce, mongo-shell

My collection of products consists of `_id`, `product/title`, `product/price` and `reviews`. `Reviews` is an array with all reviews for that specific product. I am trying to print out 10 products with the largest number of reviews but can't find the right solution.
This is what I tried so far:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    emit(this._id, {
        product: this,
        count_reviews: this.reviews.length
    });
};

var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {
    var count = 0;
    var product;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        count += value.count_reviews;
        product = value.product
    });
    return { count_reviews: count, product: product};
};

db.products.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {
    out: { inline: 1},
    query: {},
    sort: { count_reviews: -1 },
    limit: 10
});
```

When I run this code it prints out 10 elements, but not with the largest number of reviews.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Looks like you store date values as string, you should **never** do that, it's a design flaw. Store proper `Date` objects. Same applies for numeric values, store them as number, not as strings.

Comment: Is it possible to make that change now with convert function?

Comment: Yes, you can convert the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use mapReduce (unless you're on a version so old you have to)

I'd use an aggregation, if you have strict data - you can omit the `$match`, if you have "strictish" data (e.g., it's an array or missing) you can use a simpler match: `{ reviews: { $exists: true } }`

```js
db.products.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    "value.reviews": { $type: "array" }
  }
},
{
   $set: { review_count: { $size: "$value.reviews" } }
},
{
   $sort: { review_count: -1 },
},
{
   $limit: 10
}
])
```

Comment: I have already tried something like that but end up with: 'PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing' on server localhost:27017.

Comment: oh interesting - so you have records where the data is missing? There's a way around that. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @duje.je that work for you?

Comment: Sadly no...no error now but doesn't print anything.

Comment: can you edit your question with a code snippet of your doc structure?

Comment: I did, sorry if there is a better way to do this. I'm begginer with MongoDB

Comment: much better to copy/paste in text - that way I can copy/paste it into mongo to test

Comment: I'm not super familiar with studio3t - but it looks like your document is nested inside a `value` field? Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, it is nested inside a value field.

Comment: That's an unusual structure. Updated the answer